# How to select limited rows based on column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new in MySQL. This may be easy, but out of my logic

I have a `product_table` which has 5 columns

```
id
product_name
product_image
description
category_id
```

in this table `category_id` has multiple rows with the same id

for example

`category` field has 300 rows with `category_id` '4' and 100 rows with `category_id` '3' so on....

I want to select only 5 rows per `category_id`
for example 
5 rows for `category_id` 4 and 5 rows for `category_id` 3 like this.

Comment: Please do not use all caps, it is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is very rude. I have edited it out, but please keep this in mind.

Comment: @mark thanks for edit. I was use caps for highlight the senetence

Comment: If you need to highlight things, better to use italics or maybe bold, but again, overdoing that actually hurts readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from 
    (SELECT category_id,
        id,
        CASE WHEN @gr=category_id THEN @rn:=@rn+1 ELSE @rn:=0 END as row_number,
        @gr:=category_id
     FROM the_table, (select @rn:=0, @gr:=null) as sess
     order by category_id, id) sub
WHERE sub.row_number<5
```

You can introduce session variables and order your data counting member in each group. Then leave only members with group number less than 5

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE category_id = '1' LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE category_id = '2' LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE category_id = '3' LIMIT 5
.
.
.
```

If there are just a few category, then this should be fine.